# login a user without login() function in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have used the User model for storing data of normal user but I want to store data of some special user in other model but than how will I be able to authenticate these special users and login them .Can I use the authenticate() and login() functions with other model also other than User model?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom user model inheriting from django's AbstractUserModel which will have all functionalities of the user model and you can add more custom fields. You will also need to have a Custom Model Manager for this.

The Model

```
from django.db import model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .manager import UserManager
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True,unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,unique=True,max_length=15)
    profile=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/',default='profile/profile-user.png')
    about=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=200)
    saved=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD='id'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]
```

The Manager (manager.py)

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations=True

    def create_user(self,email=None,phone=None,password=None,**extra):
        if not email and not phone:
            raise ValueError('Either Email or Phone is required')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,phone=phone,**extra)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,password,**extra):
        extra.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        extra.setdefault('is_active',True)
        phone = 'default'

        if extra.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('is_staff should be True for Superuser'))

        return self.create_user(phone=phone,password=password,**extra)
```

You can register this Model just like any other( in admin.py file)

```
admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```